# How to add 'instance keys' to a keras model input for batch prediction in gcloud ai-platform?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gcloud

I'm trying to add 'keys' to match the batch prediction output from Google AI Platform, however my model input just allows for one input.

It looks like that:

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_len,))

x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_words, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(128, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, kernel_size=3, padding="valid", kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform")(x)

avg_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
max_pool = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([avg_pool, max_pool])

preds = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(input, preds)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['accuracy','binary_crossentropy'])
```

I came across [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extend-a-canned-tensorflow-estimator-to-add-more-evaluation-metrics-and-to-pass-through-ddf66cd3047d), but can't figure out how to apply this to my code.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: US ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. Converting a text file from US ASCII to UTF-8 will not change anything, because every ASCII file is also a UTF-8 file (but not vice versa). I think the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: You're right. I figured that the problem is in the 'keys' part. My input for the model just accepts 'input_1', so I need to adapt the input to be able to accept 'keys' too. I came across [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/pull/158/files) and [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extend-a-canned-tensorflow-estimator-to-add-more-evaluation-metrics-and-to-pass-through-ddf66cd3047d), but can't figure out how to adapt it to my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your code, you could do something like this:

First, get the key value from the input:

```py
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_len,))
key_raw = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), name='key')
```

[Reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Reshape#__init__) it to use later for concatenation

```
key = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1,), input_shape=())(key_raw)
```

[Concatenate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Concatenate#top_of_page) the key with the final result

```
preds = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")(x)
preds = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([preds, key])
```

Add it to the input of your model

```
model = tf.keras.Model([input, key_raw], preds)
```

Input json file example:

```
{"input_1": [1.2,1.1,3.3,4.3], "key":1}
{"input_1": [0.3, 0.4, 1.5, 1], "key":2}
```

Now, you can get the key as the last element of the prediction result.
Output example:

```
[0.48686566948890686, 0.5113844275474548, 1.0]
[0.505149781703949, 0.5156428813934326, 2.0]
```

Comment: Thanks @Tiaquetzal! I think I got somewhere, but still struggling with shaping the preds output. I get the following error: ```A target array with shape (40069, 2) was passed for an output of shape (None, 3) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output. ``` I am basically input two numpy arrays of the same length and then fitting them doing that: ```baseline_model = model.fit([x_train, x_train_array], y_train, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=5, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=1)```

Comment: `y_train` is the [target data](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit). The predictions of your model are now a tensor `(None, 3)` because of the additional key. So, you must add an additional column to `y_train` to match the `preds` with the targets

Comment: Glad it worked! Consider choosing the answer as selected

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can change the serving function serialized to SavedModel (or a second serving function). This is handy because you can have one serving infrastructure (i.e. TFServing, Google Cloud AI Platform online/batch) serve both keyed and unkeyed predictions. Also, you can add keys to a SavedModel when you don't have access the underlying keras code that generated it.

```py
tf.saved_model.save(model, MODEL_EXPORT_PATH)

loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_EXPORT_PATH)

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None], dtype=tf.string),tf.TensorSpec([None, 28, 28], dtype=tf.float32)])
def keyed_prediction(key, image):
    pred = loaded_model(image, training=False)
    return {
        'preds': pred,
        'key': key
    }

loaded_model.save(KEYED_EXPORT_PATH, signatures={'serving_default': keyed_prediction})
```

More examples [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extend-a-keras-model-5effc083265c) and the notebook [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/blogs/batch_predictions/batch_predictions_keras.ipynb).